# After upgrading react-native and expo packages, getting dependency issue with 'com.facebook.react'

Tags: react-native, expo, react-android, expo-updates, react-native-upgrade

I have upgraded the Expo package to 49.0.0 and the React Native package to 0.72.6. After the upgrade, I started getting the error 'Could not find com.facebook.react:react-native:0.72.6.'

Has anyone faced a similar issue?

[image]